# Where to start with multi-touch based applications for Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7, multi-touch

I currently develop vb.net and .NET web applications using Studio 2008.

I want to start developing applications for this device....
http://exopc.com/en/exopc-slate.php
A review of the product to give you more of an idea can be found here...
http://kevindark.co.uk/Blog.aspx?i=1&tg=EXOPC
Demonstration videos of capabilities can be found here....
http://www.youtube.com/user/darkkevind1978?feature=mhum

I don't really know where to start! Where do I go for the multi-touch dev kit? Can I add it in to Studio 2008?

Could someone create a very basic sample app for me as a sample so that I know where to start, that perhaps interacts with a touch command?

Thanks in advance,
Kev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your best bet, if you're doing a new app from scratch, is to move up to Visual Studio 2010 and WPF 4, and use the touch capabilities in WPF. Some great samples at http://multitouch.codeplex.com/ should get you started.

Also consider the Surface Toolkit for a set of controls (buttons, checkboxes etc) that are way easier to touch than the usual WPF ones and do nice things with no code on your part. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee957351.aspx for instructions, http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=801907a7-b2dd-4e63-9ff3-8a2e63932a74 to actually download it (including a small runtime you need to deploy with your apps.)

Comment: @Kevin updated the answer - 2.5 months is a long time in this field :-)